# Is this file a mounted volume?

Tags: macos, file, applescript, mount-point

**My Situation:**

I'm trying to make a Trash subsitute for my desktop using Applescript. If I double-click it, I want it to open `~/.Trash`. If I drag a file or folder to it, I want it to move said file or folder to the Trash. And, relevant to this question, if I drag a mounted volume to it I want it to eject said volume.

**My code:**

```
on open droppeditems
    set filesForTrash to droppeditems as text

    if filesForTrash ends with ":" then
        display dialog "1"
        set found to false

        repeat with volume in (list disks)
            display dialog (volume as string)
            if (volume as string) is (filesForTrash as string) then
                set found to true
                try
                    tell application "Finder"
                        eject filesForTrash
                    end tell
                end try
            end if
        end repeat

        if found is false then
            try
                tell application "Finder"
                    move filesForTrash to trash
                end tell
            end try
        end if

    else
        try
            tell application "Finder"
                move filesForTrash to trash
            end tell
        end try
    end if

end open

do shell script "open ~/.Trash"
```

**My problem:**

I've created a pretty basic DMG with iDMG and mounted it. I drag it to the application, but in the `repeat with volume in (list disks)` it fails to recognise that the volume I drag to it is one of those found in `list disks`, and so tries to `tell application "Finder" to move filesForTrash` when `filesForTrash` is a volume and so cannot be Trashed.

**My ideal solution:**

I need a way that my code will accept volumes, determine that they are volumes and then eject them rather than attempt to Trash them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `droppeditems` is a **list** of alias specifiers, coercing a list to text concatenates the HFS paths, the code cannot work.

You have to use a loop to handle each dropped item separately.

This is a different approach:

`System Events` gets the `volume` of the item and checks against the `POSIX path` to determine if it's a volume.

- If the item is a volume and ejectable the volume will be ejected
- If the item is a volume and not ejectable nothing happens.
- Otherwise the item is trashed.

---

```
on open droppeditems
    repeat with anItem in droppeditems
        tell application "System Events"
            set diskItem to disk item (anItem as text)
            set itemVolume to volume of diskItem
            set isVolume to ("/Volumes/" & itemVolume) is POSIX path of diskItem
        end tell
        tell application "Finder"
            if isVolume and ejectable of disk itemVolume is true then
                eject disk itemVolume
            else if not isVolume then
                move anItem to trash
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

If you want to trash also non-ejectable volumes remove `if not isVolume then` after `else`